# Google Apps Script HTMLservices append HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi GAS StackOverflow guides,

How do you append another HTML code/file after the initial doGet mentioned here?  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#HTMLFiles

It says it can append using HtmlOutput class but no success with:

```
function doSomething() {
//append another HTML file
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('headers');
}

function doSomething2() {
//append another HTML file
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile.append('headers');
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The append method on an HtmlOutput is for appending in the initial doGet function (if you are building up your HTML piece by piece). You can't use it to append more stuff later, but you can use the regular document.append() that you'd use in any other client-side JavaScript to do this. Something like this:

**On the client**

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(x) { document.append(x); }).doSomething2()
```

**On the server**

```
function doSomething2() { return "the stuff I want to append"; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Corey. Used your example in my test project but no success.

**On the client**
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>New Data</td>
       <td>Pending Projects</td>
        <td>Completed Projects!</td>
       <td>
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Check" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessFunction(function(x) { document.append(x); }).doSomething()" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

**On the server**
    function doSomething() {
    return "<center>Text Text Text</center>";
    }

Comment: Hi,

Anyone have any other insights?  Appreciate it.

Comment: 1: Use withSuccessHandler, not withSuccessFunction (my error; I corrected the answer above.)

2: I was just giving an example of how to append on the client. document.append only works in certain circumstances. For a more general answer, try this:

function(x) { var d = document.createElement(\'div\'); d.innerHTML=x; document.body.appendChild(d) }

Comment: Hi Corey, That works. Server function now returns a string. A follow-up: Is it possible to return an HTML file (via Scripts) on the server function?  Thank you.

Comment: You can return the content of an HTML file by loading the file and returning the HtmlOutput.getContent(), aka the file's text.